# Memory leak with WCF / Castle

Tags: wcf, memory-leaks, castle-windsor, wcf-data-services

We are having a problem with a memory leak between our MVC3 web application and our WCF data layer service.

I believe the problem is from the WCF side, although cannot track it down. I've searched the web and these forums, but have not been able to find the cause. Any help would be much appreciated!

So - the initial symptom was the size of the w3wp process associated with the backend growing constantly. We can see it grows by a variable amount (order of magnitude 100kb) every time a simple call is made from the web app that calls a service.

Running Jetbrains memory profile against the app we can see that

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransmissionStrategy.SlidingWindow
```

is by far and away the culprit. At app startup there are 4 objects instantiated with a tiny amount of memory (6.4% of total), after mild use it rises to > 200 objects, ~50% of total. Continued use drives this towards 100%. I've never heard of this before, but some googling indicates that it is used (amongst other things) in the transmission of data to and from the WCF layer.

My current line of thought is that processes are being created, but never released correctly. Our services are created from Castle, and registered from the web end as:

```
public static IWindsorContainer RegisterWcfService<TS, TI>(this IWindsorContainer container)
 where TI : TS
 where TS : class
{
 container.Register(Component.For<TS>().ImplementedBy<TI>().Named(typeof(TI).Name)
     .Interceptors<LoggingInterceptor>()
     .Interceptors<ExceptionHandlerInterceptor>()
     .LifeStyle.Transient
     .AsWcfService(
        GetServiceModel<TS, TI>()
        ));

 return container;
}
```

As suggested in other threads, we are using

```
container.Kernel.ReleasePolicy = new NoTrackingReleasePolicy();
```

to ensure components should be correctly released. We are not explicitly disposing of any of our service references, although I believe the above should be enough. Does anyone have any recommendations or suggestions on where our leak might be coming from?

Comment: are you sure that the memory is not able to be reclaimed?  Is total machine memory under pressure?  Could it be that as there is plenty of memory it just doesn't reclaim it?

Comment: Completely sure, it's not being reclaimed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, manually managing disposal of WCF proxies is the most reliable way to ensure the release of memory for garbage collection and the release of network resources. This [brief blog post](http://omaralzabir.com/do-not-use-using-in-wcf-client/) explains some of the issues that cause WCF proxies to leak memory & network resources. Since you already configure the container to create transient proxy instances, you should wrap your service call logic in a pattern similar to the one shown in the article.

If this doesn't solve your issue, you many need to wade through a memory dump using WinDbg to find what the actual GC root holding a reference chain to the `SlidingWindow` instances.

PS: Don't be tempted to use a longer lived scope (request or perish the thought, a singleton) to try to solve this issue. The solution is proper disposal of the proxy instances. I found this out the hard way... ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I feared this may be the case.